# How to solve for x when it is in the power of e?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this following equation:
$ ae^{mx}+b e^{-mx}=c$

How do I solve for x here?? Assume that all a,b,c, and m are real numbers.

Comment: Is there supposed to be an $e$ after the $b$?

Comment: Note that $r^y+r^{-y}=s$ is $(r^y)^2-sr^y+1=0$.